# REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I need to use REGEXP_REPLACE to do the following :

```
 If word starts with 'ABCD' then replace first four(4) chars with 'FFFF'
    else
 If word starts with 'XYZ' then replace first three(3) chars with 'GGG'
```

How do I use REGEXP_REPLACE to do conditional replace ?

Comment: Is the use of REGEXP_REPLACE part of the problem statement, or only part of the solution you want to offer? The best answer (given by Gordon Linoff) does not use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and string operations:

```
select (case when word like 'ABCD%'
             then 'FFFF' || substr(word, 5)
             when word like 'XYZ%'
             then 'GGG' || substr(word, 4)
             else word
        end) as new_word
```

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be `REGEXP_REPLACE` you'll have to combine two function calls:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(word,'^ABCD','FFFF')
  ,'^XYZ', 'GGG')
```

But I would prevere Gordon's `case`approach...